# monitor table activities

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an application consisting of several classes to import data from the file. The import results in several tables getting updated/deleted/inserted. There are many of the stored procedures and triggers called to carry out this task. How do I have the activity monitored at the table level in the database? All I want to have a summary of tables affected by the import, the mode of insert/deletes/update (through triggers/stored procedures/application). Your solutions on this would be greatly helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to track changes in the sql server itself.

You may want to...

- create triggers on all tables and let them write to a log
- setup a SQL Server Profiler and interpret everything he has monitored for a specific session
- use CDC (which is way over the top for this)

etc. etc. etc.

But maybe the easiest thing for you in this situation may be to use `fn_dblog` which is nearly undocumented.

It is a bit like a look back in time. You can see every changes which happened in your System in the last minutes, days, hours and maybe days.

```
SELECT *
FROM fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
```

You'll get back a huge list (beware!). 
In this list, you can find different operation-types. Some of them are:

- `LOP_INSERT_ROWS` -- Insert
- `LOP_MODIFY_ROW` -- Update
- `LOP_DELETE_ROWS` -- Delete

You can also see the `AllocUnitName`. This represents the table where those operation-types happened.

Additionally you can filter all of those records using the `Transaction Id` or the `Transaction Name`. The `Transaction Name` will be just defined on the start of the transaction (Operation-Type: `LOP_BEGIN_XACT`). Another way to filter it, may be the columns `Begin Time` and `End Time`. You can also filter after a specific `Spid`. But beware, not all columns will be filled everywhere. It may be that you need to join those values or just try to get the transaction first and find all rows which where changed with those transaction.